# How to pg_upgrade with an User-defined Data-Directory

Tags: postgresql, pg-upgrade

Running PostgreSQL on MANJARO, the actual `/var/lib/postgres/data/postgresql.conf` defines my Data-Directory:

```
data_directory = '/mnt/Data/.../PostgreSQL'
```

Now I'm facing the upgrade from PostgreSQL 13 to 14 and I'm thinking to use pg_upgrade, as [described in the Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL).
The [Step 4.) described there](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL) is pretty clear, but is it also sufficient for my `data_directory = '/mnt/Data/.../PostgreSQL'` or do I need to take additional actions?
Furthermore, I'm thinking to have versioned directories, e.g.

```
/var/lib/postgres/data/14/
/mnt/Data/.../PostgreSQL/14/
```

What should I consider to realize that?
Thank you!

Comment: I am not certain what your question is (you cannot expect a tutorial as an answer). `pg_upgrade` should just work. If not, please detail your problems.

Comment: Thank you: As I described, the Step 4 described in the Wiki, is related to /var/lib/postgres/*, what do I need to do in addition in regards to my data_directory = '/mnt/Data/.../PostgreSQL'? Running pg_upgrade --check failed as well, I could not even find out, which data_dirs to define ('/var/lib/postgres/*' OR '/mnt/Data/.../PostgreSQL'

Answer (score 1):

When running `pg_upgrade`, point the `--old-datadir` and `--new-datadir` options to the directories that contain `postgresql.conf` (not to the actual data directories). I admit that this is confusing; however, [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html) says:

> `-d configdir`
> `--old-datadir=configdir`
>
> the old database cluster configuration directory; environment variable `PGDATAOLD`

Note that the wording is “cluster configuration directory”, not “data directory”.

Comment: Thank you, I had studied the documentation which is almost the same as your answer. But: what are the dirs in my case:  
/var/lib/postgres/data/13/  

OR  

/mnt/Data/.../PostgreSQL/13/  
For whatever reason, the environment variables are empty here ...

Comment: You have to use the directory that contains `postgresql.conf`.